# From sub class to super class and back again

Tags: java, design-patterns, dispatch

So imagine this,

Given a class hierarchy:

```
S (abstract)
A extends S
B extends S
```

Let's say we have a chain of connected components handling objects of types of A and B. For example:
`K1.handle(A) -> K2.handle(A) -> K3.handle(A)`
meaning that K1 takes in A and calls K2 with A which calls K3 with A.

Similarly we have:
`K1.handle(B) -> K2.handle(B) -> K3.handle(B)`

Thing is K2's logic does not depend on the sub type of S. So we could replace K2.handle(A) and K2.handle(B)  with K2.handle(S). But the problem is that at some point we need to do type checking of the actual object type to call correct K3 method.

How does one solve this without doing `if` or `switch` etc. statements that inspect the type/properties of the actual objects?

Is it the visitor pattern I need to look into?

To give a concrete example of the case. Let's say K1 is a REST controller with different POST endpoints for A and B. It deserialises the payload and validates the data, then it passes the object to K2 for further processing. All the steps included in K2 (and other components it calls) are happy to work with objects of type S only. But in the very end at K3 we need to know the actual type of S.

Comment: *"K2's logic does not depend on the sub type of S"* --- Sure it does, because calling `K3.handle()` is part of that logic, so it does depend on subtype of `S`.

Comment: This question is substantially too abstract to provide a good answer. Common patterns include having a framework resolve the handlers (like Spring `ApplicationEvent`) or using Chain of Responsibility.

Comment: As long as the method called by K3 is defined in S, then both A and B will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> But in the very end at K3 we need to know the actual type of S.

So all the logic in `K2.handle()` comes before the call to `K3.handle()`.

Also, since `K3.handle(A)` and `K3.handle(B)` cannot be `K3.handle(S)`, according to the wording of the questing, it would appear that `K3.handle()` is an overloaded method, even though that's not explicitly stated in the question.

One way to do this is then to move common logic to an internal helper method:

```java
public class K2 {
    public void handle(A a) {
        handleInternal(a);
        K3.handle(a);
    }
    public void handle(B b) {
        handleInternal(b);
        K3.handle(b);
    }
    private void handleInternal(S s) {
        // K2 logic here
    }
}
```

Or you could use a method reference, allowing the call to K3 to be embedded in the K2 logic, not just at the end:

```java
public class K2 {
    public void handle(A a) {
        handleInternal(a, K3::handle); // method reference to K3.handle(A)
    }
    public void handle(B b) {
        handleInternal(b, K3::handle); // method reference to K3.handle(B)
    }
    private <T extends S> void handleInternal(S s, Consumer<T> k3_handle) {
        // Some K2 logic here
        k3_handle.accept(s);
        // More K2 logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given sample classes:

```
class S {}

class A extends S {
    public int getAInfo() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B extends S {
    public int getBInfo() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

We can make an interface `K` that takes advantage of a bounded type parameter as follows:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface K<T extends S> {
    void handle(T s);

    @SafeVarargs
    static <FT extends S> K<FT> compose(K<FT> finalK, K<? super FT>... ks) {
        return s -> {
            Stream.of(ks).forEach(k -> k.handle(s));
            finalK.handle(s);
        };
    }
}
```

We can then use `K.construct` to make a new instance of `K` that will forward an `s` throughout an entire pipeline of `K`s. This pipeline of `K`s is structured such that all but the last `k` are generic handlers, accepting any instance of `S`. Only the last one will accept an instance of a specific subclass of `S`, namely `FT` (abbreviation for "final type").

With this `K` definition, all the following statements compile:

```
K<S> k1 = s -> System.out.println("K1 handled.");
K<S> k2 = s -> System.out.println("K2 handled.");
K<A> k3A = a -> System.out.println(a.getAInfo());
K<B> k3B = b -> System.out.println(b.getBInfo());

K.compose(k3A, k1, k2).handle(new A()); // Propagates instance of A through pipeline
K.compose(k3B, k1, k2).handle(new B()); // Propagates instance of B through pipeline
```

yet the ad-hoc polymorphism of all the `K`s in the pipeline that are *not* the last `k` is still maintained, as both these statements compile as well:

```
k1.handle(new S());
k2.handle(new S());
```

One downside I see in this solution is that, unlike the other answer, the `K` handlers must be *strictly* sequentially executed, and calls to the next `k`'s handler cannot happen in the middle of the previous one. Through I still think you can extend this type of design to enable support for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a visitor pattern.

The visitor is

```
interface K {
    void handle(A a);
    void handle(B b);
}
```

and `K1`, `K2`, `K3` implement it.

What S needs is a method `visit(K)` with the implementations

```
class A implements S {
    public void visit(K visitor) {
        visitor.handle(this); // calls the handle(A) method
    }
}
class B implements S {
    public void visit(K visitor) {
        visitor.handle(this); // calls the handle(A) method
    }
}
```

Your list (ie your chain) is just a `List<K>` with something like

```
List<K> handlers = Arrays.asList(new K1(), new K2(), new K3());
S sample = new A();
for (K visitor : handlers) {
    sample.visit(visitor);
}
sample = new B();
for (K visitor : handlers) {
    sample.visit(visitor);
}
```

Here's a [running version](https://ideone.com/fV7Moh).

Comment: Should it be `sample.visit(visitor)`, since `visit` is defined under `S`?

Comment: @MarioIshac Yes, corrected, thank you. There might be other minor issues since I just typed it down, added a runnable version at ideone.

Answer (score 0):

I never really appreciated Visitor pattern, so here's an alternative with using functional composition and Java generics. I don't think you need to add methods to existing classes or interfaces using this approach.

You can use the fact that `K3.handle(A)` is a `Consumer<A>` which you can easily transform into a `Function<A,A>` by using `Function<A,A> handleA = a -> k3.handle(a); return a;`. This returns the input element typed as `A`, which you can then `compose()` with the other functions `k2::handle` and `k1::handle`. You cannot do that as a chained call on a single line because that breaks Java's type inference, but this works:

```
K k1 = new K1();
K k2 = new K2();
// construct A chain
K3A specificA = new K3A();
Function<A, A> handleA = a -> specificA.handle(a);
handleA = handleA.compose(k2::handle);
handleA = handleA.compose(k1::handle);
```

In this case,

```
class K {
    <T> T handle(T item);
}
class K3A {
    A handle(A item) { ... }
}
```

but if the `handle()` methods are `void`, you can wrap them into lambdas as I've described above.

Not sure if you find this more readable/maintainable, but again I dislike Visitor so much that I had to try.

Here's a [running sample](https://ideone.com/BqlEqf) and here a [fork with the wrapped version](https://ideone.com/fmWxvh) (which represents exactly the case you presented IIUC, and without any code change in `S`, `A`, `B` or any of the `K`s).

Comment: I will experiment with this, but I dislike the fact that there needs to be someone who knows that k1,k2 and k3 exist and how they are linked. It would be agains the current architecture of Spring injected services calling services.

Comment: For example in this approach my REST API endpoint (K1) would need to have instance of the database access (K3).

Comment: @Raipe Well someone will need to fill the list in your example as well, no? The way I do this kind of thing in Spring is to have a `@Configuration` that provides the single `K` methods and one that creates the composition end object (ie, the constructed chain).